# Fetch post meta data on POST request

Tags: post-meta

I have inserted values product-price, name and size in wordpress. The insert code is below

```
function products_save_postdata($post_id) {
  if (isset ($_POST['price'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'price', esc_attr($_POST['price']));
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['product_name'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'product_name', esc_attr($_POST['product_name']));
  }
  if (isset ($_POST['size'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'size', esc_attr($_POST['size']));
  }
}
```

How can i fetch this inserted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type'=>'products','posts_per_page'=>10,'number_posts'=>10);
$products = get_posts($args);

foreach($products as $product) {

$productid = $product->ID;

 echo $producttitle = $product->post_title;

echo $productdescription = $product->post_content;

echo get_post_meta($productid ,'price', TRUE);

echo get_post_meta($productid ,'product_name', TRUE);

echo get_post_meta($productid ,'size', TRUE);

}
?>
```

if the value is empty it shows null otherwise

Comment: Thnx. But i want to create a list which i have inserted.

Comment: didn't understand can u explain in more details

Comment: I have inserted 10 products with its details in admin part. I want to display a list of these products in user part means in front end.

Comment: i have edited my code

Comment: it shows "Hello world!Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging! "

Comment: do you have created any post type for products or using any ecommerce plugin

Comment: Sorry my net was disturbing. Yaa i have created my post_type it is "product".

Comment: i have edited my code once again